# How do I create a word count that does not include blank spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to python, and I was tasked with creating a function that accepts a string as the parameter and return the number of **words** in the string.

I am having trouble with the spaces and the blank string I assigned. I feel like I am missing something, but am a bit lost as to what's missing or what I've messed up. Also we can't use split.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated

This is what I have so far:

```
def word_count(str):
count = 1
for i in str:
    if (i == ' '):
       count += 1                    
print (count)
```

word_count('hello') --> Output = 1 (so far correct)

word_count('how are you?') --> Output = 3 (also correct/at least what i am looking for)

word_count(' this string has wide spaces ') --> Output = 7 (Should be 5...)

word_count(' ') --> Output = 2 (Should be ''. I think it's doing count(1+1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code as an improvement

```
def word_count(str):
    count = 1
    for i in str:
        if (i == ' '):
           count += 1
    if str[0] == ' ':
        count -= 1
    if str[-1] == ' ':
        count -= 1
    print (count)
```

your error is because your counting spaces if they start at beginning or appear at end.
NOTE that you can't pass empty string `""` since this is evaluated to `NONE`, and trying to index it will cause an error

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

```
def word_count(input_str):
    return len(input_str.split())


count = word_count(' this is a test ')
print (count)
```

It basically removes the leading/trailing spaces and splits the phrase into
a list.

If, on the offchance you need to use a loop:

```
def word_count(input_str):
    count = 0
    input_str = input_str.strip()
    for i in input_str:
        if (i == ' '):
            count += 1                    
    return count

count = word_count(' this is a test ')
print (count)
```

Comment: The call to strip is unnecessary. The split() method splits on \s+.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be when there is a blank in front or behind the sentence. A way to fix this is by using a built in function 'strip'. For example, we can do the following:

```
example_string = " This is a string "
print(example_string)
stripped_string = example_string.strip()
print(stripped_string)
```

The output of the first string will be

```
" This is a string "
```

The output of the second string will be

```
"This is a string"
```